# Django Detail View and update Filefield

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the model

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='.cc')
    codefile = models.FileField(...)
```

with the serializer

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'codefile')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'name')
```

and the viewset

```
class FileViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                            mixins.ListModelMixin,
                            mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.FileSerializer



    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(name=self.request.data['codefile'])
```

So by going to localhost:8000/files I see a list of all File-objects and can upload new files via post.

How can I implement a detail-view with the django rest framwork, such that at

localhost:8000/files/5

I would see the name and file of the File with pk=5, and with the option to update/reupload this codefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that is very easy - since you want full REST actions, you can just subclass [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) instead:

```py
class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(name=self.request.data['codefile'])

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(name=self.request.data['codefile'])
```

We just have to create `perform_update` method identical to your `perform_create` to update `name` field when we change file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add this class to your view:

```
class FileDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
```

and of course you'll need to update your `url_patterns` in your `urls.py`.

I guess you would need to add:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('file/<int:pk>/', views.FileDetail.as_view()),
    ...
]
```